# returning pattern in string

Tags: c, loops

I am writing programm from codewars site
It should return pattern ie.

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
7777777
88888888
999999999
10101010101010101010
```

my code below

```
char* pattern(const int n)
{
    char *result = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*n*n*n*n);
    char *temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 6);
    memset(result, '\0', (n*n*n*n));
  memset(temp,'\0',6);
    if (n<1)
        return "";
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            sprintf(temp, "%d", i);
      strcat(result,temp);
      memset(temp,'\0',6);
        }
        strcat(result, "\n");
    }
    result[strlen(result) - 1] = '\0';
    return result;
}
```

I pass all basic test but random tests i get some erros. Where I have made mistake?

Comment: I pass all basic test but random tests i get some erros. what is basic test, and what is random test ? what are some errors ?

Comment: why you allocate for the result n*n*n*n bytes ?

Comment: I allocate bigger value than i will need to be honest i don't know the value of n as an input so i also try n^4 but still some errors

Comment: If n will be bigger than some value it will be imposibble to allocate enough memory so I think that n must be enough small to allocate the memory

Comment: in fact, you can calculate the length of result as my answer below

Comment: If `int` is a 32-bit value, it cannot have more than 10 digits, so `malloc(10*n)` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, never cast `malloc` as in your code.
One of the errors that i can see in you code is

```
char *result = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*n*n*n*n);
```

If `n` is big, then the size of `result` is very very huge.

You can use `sprintf` to convert `n` to string first, then you can calculate the length of result by multiplying `n` with string length of `n` (+ 1 for null character) :

```
    char str[20];
    sprintf(str, "%d", n);
    // allocate for result
    char * result = malloc(n*strlen(str) +1);
```

The complete program for test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char * pattern(int n)
{
    char str[20];
    sprintf(str, "%d", n);

    char * result = malloc(n*strlen(str) +1);
    if (!result)
      return NULL;

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        strcat(result, str);
    }

    //printf("%s", result);

    return result;
}
void print_pattern(int n) {

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        char * result = pattern(i);
        printf("%s\n", result);
        free(result);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    print_pattern(10);
    return 0;
}
```

The result:

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
7777777
88888888
999999999
10101010101010101010
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I think it doesn't work properly

Comment: I have got erros in basic test which I erlier pass. The problem is that I will need 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+2*10+2*11+2*13+2*14+...+3*101+3*102 and so on allocated memory. But you are correct.Problem can be in this line of code where I allocated memory. Anyway thank you for your answers

Comment: I see a `malloc` in a loop, but no mention of `free` anywhere, that's a bad idea. There is also no reason to allocate inside the function, just calculate `strlen` for `INT_MAX` and use a single buffer.

Comment: it's my fault, i forget to free the result in print function. Thanks. I will update

Comment: allocate inside the function, why not ? just a solution for string in c. Are your sure use your solution is better ?

Comment: I think that said something wrong. N not always is equal 10. Variable n is paramter of function pattern. Variable n could be for example 5 or 10, or 200 or 555. Solution must be something what I can't see

Comment: In fact, you can change value of n in main function. You can input n from command line, or scanf as you want. N=10 just for test.